# symfony2 / doctrine2 - dql statement onetoMany

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have an entity driver and an entity car. One driver has many cars.
I have the following dql query:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('select d, c FROM driver d JOIN d.cars c WHERE c.color=:color');                
$query->setParameter('color', $color);
$query->setFirstResult((int)$offset ? $offset*15 : 0 );
$query->setMaxResults(15);
```

The resultlist has 5 rows. But when i perform the created sql query in the console, then i have 15 rows. 
When i change the join type to left join, the rows are count by car not by driver. But i'm using a pager for read the drivers who have red cars.

Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing fetch join queries with Doctrine, there is more than one row returned for each entity. If you use setMaxResults on these queries, some entities are discarded.

Read this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

The solution is here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

Comment: Great answer! About Pagination, reading about it, I can only assume it would be killer expensive operation for same larger datasets...

Comment: Cache is your friend in this case

Comment: i'm ordering my query by a date, but the result is messy. the last 3 rows are from the second detected date. by example dataset: 2012-03-20, 2012-03-21, 2012-03-22, 2012-03-23, 2012-03-24, 2012-03-21